# can't get R.anim in my project

Tags: android, android-animation

I started some android programming and I am trying to do some animation in my activity. but all references are using interpolators and files from res/anim folder which I can't find in my project. Also, when I am using R.anim I am getting an error that it doesn't exist.

Is there any API to download?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to import the R file. You should see something like below in the import list of your class file.

```
import <your.app.package>.R
```

Comment: It works fine now. Thank you:) but any idea where to get the interpolator files? thank you again

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, and none of the solutions above worked. 
In the end, I got it to work by referencing it as `android.R.anim` as explained [here](http://joshua14.homelinux.org/blog/?p=1202).

Comment: Thanks this solution worked for me but I ended up creating my own "res/anim" folder in my project and copying the animation files I needed to use into my project from the Android SDK location because I wanted to use a custom duration in the files.

Answer (score 3):

Had similiar issue, but could access all other `R.*` locations but not `anim`.

Problem was with an `anim` xml file missing:
 `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Nothing in IDE detected any error. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

No, R file is not some API. It is a file generated by the Android build system from existing resources. If you can't find some particular references to resources, this means these resources don't exist. You should put them where they belong. Read more about [providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for your applications.

Answer (score 0):

No api.  Your config is wrong in some way.  Attach some code, possibly a screenshot of your project browser so we can see the folder/file structure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was yet another reason why my `R.anim.shake` hadn't been recognized. It was because my project is divided into 2 modules (`app` and `library`). I placed the animation file (`shake.xml`) in the `app` module while I was trying to reference it from the `library` module. Moving the `shake.xml` file to `library/src/main/res/anim` solved the problem.